# Public abstract method or interface?

Tags: .net, methods, interface, abstract

I have an abstract class with a public abstract method on it.  I'm wondering if I should just define an interface and have the abstract class implement that instead.  Is there a general rule of thumb here?  Currently it works just fine, but I want to be mindful of OO conventions.  This is currently how it looks:

```
public abstract class MySuckyClass
{ 
    public bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this.GetMember(binder.Name);

        if (result == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public abstract object GetMember(string memberName);
}
```

Comment: I can't pick one correct answer since they're all correct in their own way.  Thanks for the feedback, though.  For now, I'm just going to be lazy and keep it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a question which has a range of different answers. Will probably vary based on opinion.

Personally, I like defining interfaces and then supplying some canned functionality using an abstract class. This allows me to go back to the interface if I need to supply a different implementation, but saves me time when dealing with methods/properties that do the same thing in multiple implementations.

Comment: I understand that it has a range of different answers.  I just wanted to get some idea about why people prefer one over the other and then make up my own mind.

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to use an abstraction. In that regard, this means either an interface or an abstract class.

If your code works as it is, don't change it just to add an un-needed interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is back from 2003 but it still hold true in my mind

[Recommendations for Abstract Classes vs. Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

And you can define constructors in a an abstract class where you cannot in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great book called “Framework Design Guidelines” by Cwalina Krzysztof. If I remember rightly one of the guidelines was to use abstract classes if you want the developer to extend your class and use interfaces if you don’t.